# Brain.js пример с поколениями

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как можно написать простенький ии чтобы обучался как в этом видео

С использованием библиотеки brain.js?

Самый простой вариант, не могу понять как с этой библиотекой реализовать поколения и сделать отбор

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SH0PP6SiipM&t=170s